# Finding a unique word in string with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a unique word in my input string with JS and have written a code. However, my code doesn't work and I don't know why. Could anyone help me please?

```js
function findUniqueWord(index){
    var show = []
    var result = [...index]
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < result.length; j++) {
            if(result[i] === result[j]){
                
            }
            else{
                return show.push(result[i])
            }
            
        } 
    }
    return show
}

console.log(findUniqueWord('A2A'));
```

Comment: What does "find a unique word" mean? What do you expect `findUniqueWord('A2A')` to return?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You've only provided one word in the input, so it's always unique.

Comment: The thing is I am looking for the first character in my input which is string that is unique and is not duplicated. For example, if I enter 'Mystery' the out put be just the first unique character or 'M'.

Comment: Your code accepts an array as parameter, but based on your example, I assume your goal is to work with a string instead and find the first unique character in the string?

Comment: @MahmoudMohammadnezhad Have you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to find the first unique letter in a string, you can use `split` for create an array of string then use `reduce` for sum duplicate and last part use `Object.entries` with `indexOf` for search the first letter unique. In this example i will add a case that not exist a unique letter.

```js
function findUniqueWord(index) {
  let array = index.split('');  
  let map = array.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    prev[cur] = (prev[cur] || 0) + 1;
    return prev;
  }, {});
  let finalIndex = null;
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(map)) {
    if(value === 1){
      let tempIndex = array.indexOf(key);
      finalIndex = (finalIndex !== null && finalIndex < tempIndex) ? finalIndex : tempIndex;
    }
  }    
  return (finalIndex === null) ? 'No unique letter' : array[finalIndex];
}
console.log(findUniqueWord('Mystery'));
console.log(findUniqueWord('2A2'));
console.log(findUniqueWord('2AA'));
console.log(findUniqueWord('22AA'));
```

This method is case-sensetive if you don't need it just use `toUpperCase()` to string before call `split` method.

Reference:

- [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)